# Spring batch to Microservice conversion

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, cloud-foundry

I need to convert a spring batch to a spring boot microservice on cloud foundry. At present, the spring batch pulls the files from an FTP server and processes it.
I plan to write a set of microservices (exposed as a REST), for the individual processes that I perform in the spring batch.

So, my question is this.

Will cloud foundry have access to pull files from an FTP server (assuming cloud foundry is on a private cloud)? How will I write my microservice to handle this?

Comment: I think you would get a better answer researching the internet rather than asking this type of question here. While it is a valid question, it is not they type of question for [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/). This is for issues where something is not working and you don't understand why, not to get advice on how to do something for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

From what you have written you should really be looking at SCDF (Spring Cloud Dataflow) and Tasks. They come with an inbuilt FTP source and multiple sinks. Vote if this helps. Thx